# My setState doesn't work in my react application on context.provider

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
// TokenContext.js

import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const TokenContext = createContext();

const TokenProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const [refresh, setRefreshToken] = useState(null);

  const [isVerifyLogin, setIsVerifyLogin] = useState(false);

  const [assessmentResult, setAssessmentResult] = useState(false);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const changeToken = (newToken) => {

    setToken(newToken, () => {

      console.log("buraay geldii change : ", newToken);

      console.log("yenilenen token ", token);

    });

  };

  const changeRefreshToken = (newRefresh) => {

    setRefreshToken(newRefresh);

  };

  const changeIsVerifyLogin = () => {

    setIsVerifyLogin(true);

  };

  const changeAssestmentResult = () => {

    setAssessmentResult(true);

  };

  const fetchData = async () => {

    console.log(isVerifyLogin);

    console.log(token);

    try {

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/get-db", {

        headers: {

          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,

        },

      });

      if (!response.ok) {

        const response2 = await fetch(

          "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/refreshToken",

          {

            method: "POST",

            headers: {

              Accept: "application/json",

              "Content-type": "application/json",

            },

            body: JSON.stringify({

              refreshToken: refresh,

            }),

          }

        );

        if (response2.ok) {

          const data2 = await response2.json();

          changeToken(data2.accessToken);

          console.log(token);

          await fetchData();

        } else {

          setIsVerifyLogin(false);

        }

      } else {

        setIsVerifyLogin(true);

        const data = await response.json();

        setUsers(data);

      }

    } catch (error) {

      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);

      setIsVerifyLogin(false);

    }

  };

  return (

    <TokenContext.Provider

      value={{

        token,

        changeToken,

        isVerifyLogin,

        changeIsVerifyLogin,

        assessmentResult,

        changeAssestmentResult,

        users,

        fetchData,

        refresh,

        changeRefreshToken,

      }}

    >

      {children}

    </TokenContext.Provider>

  );

};

export { TokenContext, TokenProvider };
```

I used refresh token in my react application. While refresh token creates a new accessToken, setToken doesn't update the token state.

Comment: `setToken` doesn't take two arguments

Comment: Thank you for answering. But ı dont understand where is the two argument

Comment: The second argument that you provided is `() => {

      console.log("buraay geldii change : ", newToken);

      console.log("yenilenen token ", token);

    }`

Comment: I use like this but doesnt work again

const changeToken = (newToken) => {
    setToken(newToken);
  };

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `setState` doesn't change anything until next render cycle